# How to load data and show them as tooltip on mouseover - Angular

Tags: angular, tooltip, angular-material

I have mat-table similar to https://stackblitz.com/angular/bvydnkvdddm. I want to add tooltip for each record in column '#'. On `mouseover` I want to load data from database based on the specific number and show them in tooltip.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="number">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</th>
    <td mat-cell matTooltip={{dataFromService}} *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.number }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

If I add `onmouseover="getData()"` it fails. I get message that function `getData()` is `undefined` even this method is present in `.ts` file. The second problem is how to pass the value of specific mat-cell element? I tried to do something like that:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="number">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</th>
    <td mat-cell onmouseover="getData(row.number)" matTooltip={{dataFromService}} *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.number }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

But it also failed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach to think about.

Use the `matTooltip` as seen below.

```html
<!-- Number Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="number">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [matTooltip]="getToolTipData(row.number)">{{ row.number }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

The square brackets allow you to bind to the results of the `getToolTipData` function. Here you are passing in the `row.number` for the current row.

The `getToolTipData` function could do something like this:

```ts
getToolTipData(issueId: string): string {
    const issue = this.data.find(i => i.number === issueId);
    return `Title: ${issue.title} ||
        State: ${issue.state} ||
        Date: ${issue.created_at}`;
}
```

This returns a string that concats the `title`, `state` and `date` of the row data.

Think about pulling the data you want to have in the tooltip along with the data you are pulling to populate your table. Making an HTTP call each time you hover over a column with a tooltip could become an issue.

Comment: I want to load data only if if mouse is over, and only for specific value. In your example I load all data even if mouse is not over the element.

Answer (score 4):

Use event binding for `mouseover`, get the data from service and assign it to a variable in `*.ts` which you can use to set the value of `matTooltip` attribute in your template.

Your template should be as:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="number">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</th>
  <td mat-cell (mouseover)="getData(row.number)" 
    matTooltip={{dataFromService}} 
    *matCellDef="let row">{{ row.number }}</td>
</ng-container>
```

In your `*.ts` file:

```ts
dataFromService = '';
getData(rowNum){
 // use your service to get the data using the rowNum 
 // and assign the value you want, example 'data' to dataFromService variable
 this.dataFromService = data;
}
```

Making a request to service for every `mouseover` event is not recommended as it becomes complex to handle situations like the user keeps on moving the mouse from one row number to other - which triggers multiple events with updated row numbers, and your server requests may not be completed in that timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was having same problem for my client project. But i want to add break line between data as well. So this is how accomplished. click [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrrwqb?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts) for demo

In your html file add this code

```html
<img src="assets/icons/about.png" alt="borderLineHigh" width="15px" height="15px" matTooltip="{{getMoreInformation()}}"  matTooltipClass="test">
```

In ts file

```ts
 getMoreInformation(): string {
     return 'Address : Home \n  Tel : Number';// \n represent break line here
 }
```

in your style.css file(remember project style.css)

```css
.test {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Hope it help someone. ps keep coding